# 2012 Hyundai i20 starting problem (seems electrical)

Tags: electrical, starting, hyundai, battery-cable, i20

I have been having a slight issue with my 2012 Hyundai i20 1.4 Automatic.

Every now and then when I turn the key in the ignition, the key turns but without any of the usual lights coming on in the instrument panel and without the center information turning on. Turning further does not start the car as well.

This happens about 2 times and the 3rd attempt is usually successful. However, once the car does start, the center information display (date, time, trip computer) and the radio reset (trip distance zeros out, dates reset to 0100am in the year 2000.)

I thought it may be related to the battery but the battery is not very old (around a year old) and I've checked the terminals as well. One terminal was loose and I assumed that the problem I am experiencing was due to this but after tightening at the terminal, the problem persists...

I tried to Google this issue and found a question similar to mine on another site where the person said that even a Hyundai dealer could not find the problem...

Can anyone please offer me some words of advice. It is a bit concerning as I would hate to be left stranded somewhere with a car that does not want to start at all.

Comment: The symptoms continue to suggest a major power feed issue, albeit intermitent. Make sure that the clamps and connectors at both ends of all the big battery cables (from the battery to the starter or starter solenoid, from the battery to ground, from the battery to the + wiring, etc.) are all in good condition, clean, and tight, and that the cables themselves are in good condition. Disconnect _both ends of every cable_, clean the mating surfaces on both sides, and reattach.

Comment: @David I have done what you suggested and, thankfully, I have not had any issues since (about 2 weeks)! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem was turning the key and nothing happened it was dead. So I took negative terminal off battery and put it back on and started fine. Then it happened again and it turned out to be the earth lead running to the body of the car, cleaned it up and put it back on and hasn't happened since. Great car on fuel but that's about it the paint is starting to peel you can see through the paint on the roof and inside the doors all paint is peeling back to bare metal. Pretty bad for a 2014 model car which is kept in a garage.